# Fedora 19 and PPTP

Tags: linux, vpn, fedora, pptp

I'm having problems setting up **VPN PPTP** on Fedora 19. When I try to add new VPN I have only possibility to add ***openconnect*** or ***L2TP*** protocols.

After some googling I found out that you have to install NetworkManager-pptp plugin to enable pptp. So I did `sudo yum install NetworkManager-pptp` and I got back

`Package 1:NetworkManager-pptp-0.9.8.2-2.fc19.x86_64 already installed and latest version`.

Does anyone have an idea how can I enable PPTP VPN on Fedora 19?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just **install all required** [pptp](/questions/tagged/pptp) packages. This has changed since Kernel `3.10.3-300`. The packages are not installed by default anymore.

[image: Fedora 19 Package Manager - Additional PPTP packages]

After the installation, you'll see the `PPTP` network option:

[image: Gnome 3 Network Manager under Fedora 19]